# What do the square brackets signify in following push syntax in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, reference

I came across this syntax while reading a script. I am not sure what is the use of square brackets.

```
push @data, [ split //, $line ]; #printing this array gives crap values
```

Or to put into other words what is the difference between the above and the following?

```
push @data, (split//, $line); #printing this gives actual values
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you call ***crap*** ain't so. Use `Data::Dumper` to print out complex data structures.

Comment: In addition to `perldoc perlreftut`, check out `perldoc perllol` and `perldoc perldsc` for lots more about references - how to make and use them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code:

```
push @data, (split//, $line);
```

pushes all items on the current line into `@data`

and

```
push @data, [split //, $line];
```

Pushes a reference to an anonymous array containing those items into `@data`

If you're only ever processing one value of '$line' its probably more effective to use the former*<sup>1</sup> , however, if you are processing a file that contains multiple lines and you want to differentiate between the lines the content is on, the latter is more effective.

Consider:

```
my @data; 
while( my $line = <$fh> ){
  push @data , ( split //,  $line ); 
}
use Data::Dumper; 
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0; 
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper( \@data );
```

This will yield all of the bytes read in as separate characters, a single
array containing them all, i.e.:

```
[ "a", "b" , "c" , "\n", "d", "e", "f" ]
```

When this instead will do something entirely different:

```
my @data; 
while( my $line = <$fh> ){
  push @data , [ split //,  $line ]; 
}
use Data::Dumper; 
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0; 
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper( \@data );
```

And will instead group lines like so:

```
[ [ "a", "b", "c" , "\n" ], [ "d" , "e", "f" , "\n" ] ]
```

So you can later programmatically traverse it easier.

### Note:

```
 push @data, ( split  //, $line );
```

and

```
  push @data, split //, $line;
```

Are equivalent.

Also,

```
my @other  = ( 1,2,3 );
push @data, @other ;
```

and

```
push @data, 1,2,3;
```

are  equivalent.

From `perldoc -f push`

```
push ARRAY,LIST

Treats ARRAY as a stack, and pushes the values of LIST onto the end of ARRAY.  The length of ARRAY increases by the length of LIST.  Has the same effect as

           for $value (LIST) {
               $ARRAY[++$#ARRAY] = $value;
           }

but is more efficient.  Returns the number of elements in the array following the completed "push".
```

<sub>*1:   actually, tbf, anyone with half a brain would probably want `@data = split //, $line`</sub>

Comment: Nicely put: being able to get at specific lines later is key. If you need that, you want the references.

Comment: @kent: Thanks! Using examples to explain both conditions helped a lot in understanding the concept.

Comment: @Kent +1 for doing such a good job reading the docs for the OP. Incidentally, anyone with half an interest in Perl ought to know what `[ ... ]` is ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114522/in-perl-how-can-i-read-parts-of-lines-that-match-a-criterion/1114538#1114538 shows the code in question in context.

Comment: @Sinan: nobody is born knowing about `[]`, and it's worth remembering that references are never mentioned in _Learning Perl_. I'm not saying that references aren't important for someone serious about Perl, but I suspect that plenty of scripting or maintenance-only Perl coders rarely use references.

Answer (score 4):

That is from one of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114522/in-perl-how-can-i-read-parts-of-lines-that-match-a-criterion/1114538#1114538):

```
push @data, [ split //, $line ];
```

`@data` is an array of array refs. Each element of `@data` is a reference to an anonymous array whose entries are the characters in `$line`.

See also [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#An-Example).